# Comparing each neighboring pairs in clojure vector

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure. I found some exercises which require finding indexes for values in an array which are, for example, lower than next value. In Java I'd write

```java
    for (int i = 1; ...)
       if (a[i-1] < a[i]) {result.add(i-1)}
```

in Clojure I found keep-indexed useful:

```clj
    (defn with-keep-indexed [v]
      (keep-indexed #(if (> %2 (get v %1)) %1) (rest v)))
```

It seems to works ok, but

1. is there a better way to do so?
2. This approach should work well for "find all values" or "find first value" (wrapped in `first`). But what if I need "find last". Then I have to either `(with-keep-indexed (reverse v))` or `(last (with-keep-indexed v))`. Is there better way?

*Edit: Example: for [1 **1** 2 2 **1** 2]*

```
(with-keep-indexed [1 1 2 2 1 2])
;;=> (1 4)
```

Comment: You likely want to take a look at the function `partition` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `partition` to transform the vector to a sequence of consecutive pairs. Then use `keep-indexed` to add an index and filter them:

```clj
(defn indices< [xs]
  (keep-indexed (fn [i ys]
                  (when (apply < ys) i))
                (partition 2 1 xs)))
```

```clj
(indices< [1 1 2 2 1 2]) ;; => (1 4)
```

To find just the last such index, use `last` on this result. While it is possible to use `reverse` on the input, it does not offer any performance benefit for this problem.

Comment: I think he wanted all such indexes, with the result `[1 4]`.  Also, I don't understand the benefit of using `reverse`.

Comment: @AlanThompson My example function `indices<` gives the answer `(1 4)` as the OP asked, it matches their example. As for `reverse` I admit there is no benefit over using `last`. I think I'd confused it with [`rseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rseq), which if applicable has better performance for large input collections.

Comment: I've removed my example function using `reverse` as it wasn't helpful.

Comment: I like the `(apply < ys)`.  I forgot you don't need to destructure for something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of forming pairs of numbers and comparing each number to the next number in the sequence can be factored out in a [transducer](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) that *does not care* about whether you want your result in the form of a vector with all indices or just the last index. Forming pairs can be done using [partition](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition) as already suggested in the other answers, but I did not find a transducer implementation of that function, which would greatly facilitate. Here is a workaround that uses a mapping transducer along with some mutable state.

```
(defn indexed-pairs []
  (let [s (atom [-2 nil nil])]
    (comp (map #(swap! s (fn [[i a b]] [(inc i) b %])))
          (remove (comp neg? first)))))

(defn indices-of-pairs-such-that [f]
  (comp (indexed-pairs)
        (filter (fn [[i a b]] (f a b)))
        (map first)))
```

In this code, the function `indices-of-pairs-such-that` will return a transducer that we can use in various ways, for instance with [into](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into) to produce a vector of indices:

```
(into [] (indices-of-pairs-such-that <) [1 1 2 2 1 2])
;; => [1 4]
```

Or, as was asked in the question, we can use [tranduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/transduce) along with a reducing function that always picks the second argument if we only want the last index:

```
(transduce (indices-of-pairs-such-that <) (completing (fn [a b] b)) nil [1 1 2 2 1 2])
;; => 4
```

This is the power of transducers: they decouple sequence algorithms from the results of those algorithms. The function `indices-of-pairs-such-that` encodes the sequence algorithm but does not have to know whether we want all the indices or just the last index.

Answer (score 0):

The general problem can be solved with ...

```
(defn indexes-of-pairs [p coll]
  (let [check-list (map (fn [i x rx] (when (p x rx) i)) (range) coll (rest coll))]
    (filter identity check-list)))
```

... which returns the indexes of adjacent pairs of a sequence `coll` that are related by predicate `p`. For example,

```
(indexes-of-pairs < [1 1 2 2 1 2])
=> (1 4)
```

For your example, you can define

```
(def with-keep-indexed (partial indexes-of-pairs <))
```

Then

```
(with-keep-indexed [1 1 2 2 1 2])
=> (1 4)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to solve a problem.  Here are two alternatives, including a unit test using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  The first one uses a loop over the first (N-1) indexes in an imperative style not so different than what you'd write in Java:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn step-up-index-loopy
  [xs]    ; a sequence of "x" values
  (let-spy
    [xs    (vec xs) ; coerce to vector in case we get a list (faster)
     accum (atom []) ; an accumulator
     N     (count xs)]
    (dotimes [i (dec N)] ; loop starting at i=0
      (let-spy [j    (inc i)
                ival (get xs i)
                jval (get xs j)]
        (when (< ival jval)
          (swap! accum conj i))))
    @accum))
```

When run, it produces this output:

```
calling step-up-index-loopy
xs => [1 1 2 2 1 2]
accum => #object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x4e4dcf7c {:status :ready, :val []}]
N => 6
j => 1
ival => 1
jval => 1
j => 2
ival => 1
jval => 2
j => 3
ival => 2
jval => 2
j => 4
ival => 2
jval => 1
j => 5
ival => 1
jval => 2
```

The second one uses a more "functional" style that avoids direct indexing. Sometimes this makes things simpler, but sometimes it can appear more complicated.  You be the judge:

```
(defn step-up-index
  [xs]    ; a sequence of "x" values
  (let-spy-pretty
    [pairs         (partition 2 1 xs)
     pairs-indexed (indexed pairs) ; append index # [0 1 2 ...] to beginning of each pair
     reducer-fn    (fn [accum pair-indexed]
                     ; destructure `pair-indexed`
                     (let-spy [[idx [ival jval]] pair-indexed]
                       (if (< ival jval)
                         (conj accum idx)
                         accum)))
     result        (reduce reducer-fn
                     [] ; initial state for `accum`
                     pairs-indexed)]
    result))
```

The function `indexed` is from [the Tupelo Clojure library](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.06.06/api/tupelo.core#indexed).
When you run the code you'll see:

```
calling step-up-index
pairs => 
((1 1) (1 2) (2 2) (2 1) (1 2))
pairs-indexed => 
([0 (1 1)] [1 (1 2)] [2 (2 2)] [3 (2 1)] [4 (1 2)])
reducer-fn => 
#object[tst.demo.core$step_up_index$reducer_fn__21389 0x108aaf1f "tst.demo.core$step_up_index$reducer_fn__21389@108aaf1f"]
[idx [ival jval]] => [0 [1 1]]
[idx [ival jval]] => [1 [1 2]]
[idx [ival jval]] => [2 [2 2]]
[idx [ival jval]] => [3 [2 1]]
[idx [ival jval]] => [4 [1 2]]
result => 
[1 4]
```

Both of them work:

```
(dotest
  (newline)
  (println "calling step-up-index-loopy")
  (is= [1 4]
    (step-up-index-loopy [1 1 2 2 1 2]))
  (newline)
  (println "calling step-up-index")
  (is= [1 4]
    (step-up-index [1 1 2 2 1 2])))
```

With results:

```
-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 15.0.2
-----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

Ran 2 tests containing 2 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

The form `let-spy` is from the Tupelo Clojure library, and makes writing & debugging things easier.  See the docs for more info. When satisfied everything is working, replace with

`let-spy` => `let`

Also be sure to study the [list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) included in the template project, especially the Clojure CheatSheet.

---

Another solution using `keep-indexed` is pretty short:

```clj
(defn step-up-index
  [xs]
  (let [pairs  (partition 2 1 xs)
        result (vec
                 (keep-indexed
                   (fn [idx pair]
                     (let [[ival jval] pair]
                       (when (< ival jval)
                         idx)))
                   pairs))]
    result))

(dotest
  (is= [1 4] (step-up-index [1 1 2 2 1 2])))
```